# What is the best way to test a parser that parses configuration files written in YAML syntax?

Tags: automated-testing

I need to test a parser that parses configuration files written in YAML syntax and generates the graph. Are there any tools or approaches that would be helpful in testing the parser?

Comment: What kind of testing do you need? Something like this can be tested manually as well as with automated assistance: all that's really necessary is a supply of input-expected output pairs to work with.

Comment: @kate, thank you. Is there a tool that would generate the valid/invalid input files based on the grammar? I would like to automate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that there are already YAML parsers out there for a variety of languages, I'd be very tempted to use one of those as an oracle, and then have both parse arbitrary YAML files, and compare the output.